# How to read a backslash as a special character in Grails CSV Plugin

Tags: csv, grails, groovy, grails-plugin

i'm reading a csv file in which each properties are sperated by using pipes(|). One of the property value in  the csv file is something like this '123\56' while reading this using toCsvReader getting the value as '12356'. if the property value is given as '123\56'it will read it as '123\56'.

how to read a single backslash as a single special character?

```
inputFileContent.toCsvReader([separatorChar: '|']).eachLine { tokens ->

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/csv) you can change the `escapeChar` from the default of backslash using the configuration options.

```
inputFileContent.toCsvReader([separatorChar: '|', escapeChar: '']).eachLine { tokens ->
  ...
}
```

The above will remove the escapeChar and treat backslash as just a normal character.